# T-SQL: identify difference of x in integer sequence

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a simple table: here is an example of what the values look like (after taking out confidential values).

What I need to do is count the number of instances the difference between a Date_Nbr value and the one following is greater than 2.  I could imagine creating a second table where -- for each Group and Person, an integer count of the number of instances is placed.

Is this even possible in T-SQL?  I haven't shown any code, because I'm at a total loss.

For those who need table definitions, it would be this:

```
    Date_Nbr int not null,
    Group varchar(5) not null,
    Person varchar(5) not null
```

The values shown would exist within that table (let's call it Date_Seq).

I would be grateful for any ideas.  Thank you.

```
Date_Nbr | Group | Person

 1        C        A
 4        C        A
 5        C        A
 8        C        A
 10       C        A
 11       C        A
 13       C        A
 14       C        A
 15       C        A
```

P.S. --

I described it verbally above, but this is a visual description of what I hope to achieve, where "Count_Gaps" is the number of times a difference greater than 2 was found in the sequence of "Date_Nbr".

```
 Group | Person | Count_Gaps
 C          A     [integer value]
```

Comment: Assuming that what you posted is your source data, please add the expected result.

Comment: I appended my earlier post with a visual representation of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All records that do not have a corresponding person+group record within 2 higher.

```
SELECT
*
FROM <table> t1
LEFT join <table> t2 ON t1.group=t2.group AND t1.person=t2.person AND (t1.Date_nbr+1)=t2.Date_nbr
LEFT join <table> t3 ON t1.group=t3.group AND t1.person=t3.person AND (t1.Date_nbr+2)=t3.Date_nbr
WHERE t2.Date_nbr IS NULL
AND t3.Date_nbr IS NULL
```

Comment: This did precisely the trick.  All I had to do was change the Select statement to "Seelct Count(*) as Count_Gaps and it worked perfectly. Thank you!  I've marked this as the best answer.